# Torque wrench not clicking anticlockwise

Tags: tools, torque-wrench

I am replacing the rear dampers on my car and I wanted to use a brand new torque wrench to tighten the self locking nut to the damper shaft here :

[image]

[image: not my photo, but I use the torque wrench the same way as the ratchet shown here]

However, it is an anticlockwise tightening, so I switched the direction on the torque wrench. It is not clicking, even on the lowest setting (7 N.m), is that normal ?
The torque wrench works fine when set to a clockwise direction.

The torque wrench I am using :
[image]

Comment: Yes, that looks like a torque wrench all right.  Too bad we can't see the brand.

Comment: Certain types of torque wrench can be modified to work in the other direction. Just disassemble the drive head and backplate and switch them.

Comment: You'll find it much easier to do this work if you remove the carpet liner. It will allow you to swing the open-ended spanner while holding the wrench on the spindle in the center. With that small hole in the carpet, the implication is that you're to hold the open-ended spanner stationary which makes  this operation much more difficult.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As others have stated, your torque wrench may not be designed to work anti-clockwise.  However, more importantly -

You are not tightening those correctly.  You are meant to tighten the nut clockwise and hold the threaded shaft still with a hex key.  That is why you are finding that you need to turn it anti clockwise.

Trying to use a torque wrench the way you are doing it will likely give an incorrect torque anyway, since the body of the damper and rubber mount will likely resist the turning force as it contacts the body of the car.

Just use a spanner to tighten the nut to what you feel will be the correct torque.  It is not a fitting that needs a precise torque.

You may find that once you have the nut nipped up, you can use a long socket on your torque wrench and set it correctly if you want to, by turning the nut clockwise.

Comment: Yup. Once the nut is tight enough on the spindle, the nut will turn without the central spindle turning and you'll be able to use the torque wrench normally with a deep socket.

Answer (score 7):

I can't say "universally", but will say "most" lower end torque wrenches are only designed to work in the clockwise direction (tightening direction of most fasteners). If your torque wrench did not specifically say it would work in the anti-clockwise direction, it most likely won't.

Answer (score 3):

There exist torque wrenches that only click in the clockwise direction. In anticlockwise mode they never click. That "deceiving" mode is intended to only loosen the bolts.

Comment: I was once told that a torque wrench should not be used to loosen a bolt because it might affect the calibration.  Not sure if there was ever any truth to that but decades later I still avoid it and grab a second wrench.

Comment: @AutomateThis this is correct. The point is that one should'nt use the torque-sensing "click mechanism" to loosen bolts. In this case the counterclock direction doesn't have that mechanism, just a plain ratchet.

Comment: I think that the use of an torque wrech to loosen bolts is discouraged because one should'nt use measuring instruments for rough work, therefore it is more a matter of principles. Personally, I think that using an adequately adjusted torque wrech to loosen bolts won't hurt as long as one won't turn above the "click" torque.